# Split Column with expression in equation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for some time. I have to use a dataset similar to CSV, and there is a column with data in the form of an equation.
Here is an example of the content of this column:

```
validate employee="Claire" car="V_13" start="B02" stop="B13" start_date="21072018_095000" stop_date="21072018_103000"
```

So I would like to split this column into 6 column : validate employee, car, start, stop, start_date, stop_date and their corresponding data contained between the quotation marks, with pandas.

The dataset is already in dataframe.

Thank you in advance

Comment: this is one line of data in single column? Can you post few lines or data frame head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on Chris A answer above:

```
# Assuming DataFrame is in the form
df = pd.DataFrame(['''validate employee="Claire" car="V_13" start="B02" stop="B13" start_date="21072018_095000" stop_date="21072018_103000"''','''validate employee="Claire" car="V_13" start="B02" stop="B13" start_date="21072018_095000" stop_date="21072018_103000"'''])

# Get the column names and column values
c_names= df[0].str.findall(r'(\S+)=')
c_values= df[0].str.findall(r'"(.*?)"')

pd.DataFrame(list(c_values),columns=c_names[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with some subsequent manipulation of indexes and [unstacking](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
# Assuming DataFrame is in the form
df = pd.DataFrame(['''validate employee="Claire" car="V_13" start="B02" stop="B13" start_date="21072018_095000" stop_date="21072018_103000"''','''validate employee="Claire" car="V_13" start="B02" stop="B13" start_date="21072018_095000" stop_date="21072018_103000"'''])

df[0].str.extractall(r'(\S+)="(.*?)"').set_index(0, append=True).droplevel(1).unstack(1)
```

[out]

```
      1                                                      
0   car employee start       start_date stop        stop_date
0  V_13   Claire   B02  21072018_095000  B13  21072018_103000
1  V_13   Claire   B02  21072018_095000  B13  21072018_103000
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `df['COL']` holds those problematic values, and suppose they always begin with `"validate "`.

We could simply split the remainder of the string, e.g. `employee="Claire" car="V_13"` to a `dict` like `{'employee':'V_13', 'car':'V_13'}` and feed this to `pd.Series()` that would handle it neatly and exactly per your needs. All in all, here's a one-liner to solve this:

```py
df['COL'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({t.split('=')[0]:t.split('=')[1].strip('""') for t in x[len('validate '):].split(' ')}))
```

Of course, this assumed that the strings follow a very strict format for that simple parsing (e.g. the `.split(' ')`) to make sense. Feel free to adapt it to your specific needs / robustness, but the gist was: using a `pd.Series()` with a `dict` that was parsed out of your formatted string.